# Shopify Tracking Broken, total_price always returns 'null'

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm running into an issue with a client's Shopify store where our PPC conversion tracking suddenly stopped working and we're not quite sure why. We have a standard installation of Google Ads in the Checkout > Additional scripts section that looks like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: ***** -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-*****"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-*****');
</script>
<!-- Event snippet for Purchase conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-*****/*****',
      'value': {{ total_price | money_without_currency }},
      'currency': 'USD',
      'transaction_id': '{{order.order_number}}'
  });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

This is the same installation that we use across a few other stores and works great. It used to work on this storefront too until last week, about the time we switched to a different sales channel (has since been turned off).

During troubleshooting, I checked through the source code and noticed that a bunch of shopify variables now return null. Specifically total_price resolves to null and causes the following Javascript error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`

This is what it looks like when I inspect page source.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: ***** -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-*****"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-*****');
</script>
<!-- Event snippet for Purchase conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-*****/*****',
      'value': ,
      'currency': 'USD',
      'transaction_id': '3947'
  });
</script>
```

So 'total_price | money_without_currency' is clearly not returning the correct value and this is breaking the javascript. If I output the money as a currency it looks like this:

```
// This...
<script>console.log({{ total_price | json }});</script>

// Resolves to this
<script>console.log(null);</script>
```

I've never seen an issue like this where a shopify global variable just doesn't return anything.

I noticed one more strange difference between this store and our other working stores. Between the  tags I noticed that Shopify.Checkout.token is also returning null

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Shopify = window.Shopify || {};

  if (window.opener) {
    window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"current_checkout_page": null}), "*");
  }

  Shopify.Checkout = Shopify.Checkout || {};
  Shopify.Checkout.apiHost = "*****.myshopify.com";
  Shopify.Checkout.assetsPath = "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s";
  Shopify.Checkout.i18n = {"orders":{"order_updates":{"title":"Order updates"}}};
  Shopify.Checkout.isOrderStatusPage = true;
  Shopify.Checkout.token = null;
</script>
```

I'm not sure what the Shopify.Checkout.token is supposed to be, but I just notice that it's defined for our other working storefronts. I've tried everything that I can think of so any and all assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if at some point in the past you might've had access to a `total_price` variable in the global scope, but as of June 2020, the section about "[Adding Additional Scripts](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status#add-additional-scripts)" on the official Shopify docs says:

> The Additional scripts box is used to insert code into the template for your order status page. You can add any of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Liquid code - **You have access to the `checkout` and `shop` Liquid objects**. To learn more about their attributes, refer to *[The checkout object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/checkout)* and *[The shop object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/shop)*.

And the `checkout` object has a `total_price` property. I suspect if you refer to that property in the checkout namespace, you'll get what you're looking for.

```
<script>
  gtag(
    'event',
    'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-*****/*****',
      'value': {{ checkout.total_price | money_without_currency | json }},
      'currency': 'USD',
      'transaction_id': '{{order.order_number}}'
    }
  );
</script>
```

By the way, you might notice that I further piped `checkout.total_price | money_without_currency` to the [`json`](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/additional-filters#json) filter which will auto-escape and auto-quote values depending on their underlying types. Very handy when you're doing liquid-in-javascript.

Comment: Thank you Cameron for your response I really appreciate it. However I tried the exact solution that you recommended and it only returns an empty string. I have tried with other stores and both `total_price` by itself and `checkout.total_price` return the correct value, however with this particular store none of the checkout object's properties return anything. I'd love any other advice you may have on the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `total_price` wasn't returning anything for me, neither was `checkout.total_price`. I did however find that `order.total_price` worked, this was also true to return anything eg: `order_number`.